# How can I get 3 floating points from string to new instance of struct?

Tags: c#, regex

I have file in `.txt` format with coordinates like this:

```
Ver(0.6039f, 0.8431f, 0.8980f)
```

I need the best way for getting from this `Ver(0.6039f, 0.8431f, 0.8980f)` a new `Point3D();`

```
public struct Point3D
{
    float x,
          y,
          z;
    public Point3D(float x, float y, float z)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.z = z;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not a "Do my homework" site. You should try things, let us know what you tried and only then we can steer you to the answer/solution.

Comment: Perhaps a small hint to get you started with a regex: `([0-9.]*f)`

Comment: @JordyLangen that will match `45....3` which is invalid floating point number

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could, perhaps, do this:

```
// read the file into an array of strings - consider File.ReadAllLines() - perhaps name the array it produces "fileLines"

// iterate over the fileLines array processing one array element at a time - a good method would be to use a foreach loop
foreach(string fileLine in fileLines)
{
    // TODO: isolate the part of the string between the parenthesis

    // split the string on commas to create a string array
    var coordinates = fileLine.Split(new char[',']);

    // if there the number of string array elements is correct, allocate a Point3D element
    if (coordinates.length != 3)
    {
        throw new ApplicationException(string.Format("Invalid number of coordinates. Expected 3, got {0}.", coordinates.Length));
    }

    // use float.TryParse() to load each element of the string array into the proper member of its struct or class
    float xCoordinate;
    float yCoordinate;
    float zCoordinate;

    if (! float.TryParse(coordinates[0], out xCoordinate)
    {
        throw new ApplicationException(string.Format("Unable to parse X-coordinate {0}.", coordinates[0]));
    }
    if (! float.TryParse(coordinates[1], out yCoordinate)
    {
        throw new ApplicationException(string.Format("Unable to parse Y-coordinate {0}.", coordinates[1]));
    }
    if (! float.TryParse(coordinates[2], out zCoordinate)
    {
        throw new ApplicationException(string.Format("Unable to parse Z-coordinate {0}.", coordinates[2]));
    }
    Point3D point3D = new Point3D(xCoordinate, yCoordinate, zCoordinate);

    // TODO: stuff this point3D into an array or collection to save it

    // process the next line of the file...
}
```

I'll leave it as an exercise for the reader to fill in the some of the code between the comments.

**EDIT:**  I've gone back and filled in some of the details.  Note that this code is not structured and written as compactly as possible in an attempt to not confuse the reader.

Comment: +1 for not spoon feeding, should probably clarify `read the file into a string` though, as usually the standard way is to use [`File.ReadAllLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1.aspx), iterate though the array and parse each one individually. Also, hello STL neighbor :D

Comment: cool but this dont help me foreach i know too)

Comment: that should help you - if it doesnt let us know what part of it you're having issues with

Comment: There is also [`File.ReadLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503.aspx) (since .NET 4.0) which does not need to read the entire file into memory at once but will read line by line as you `foreach`.

Comment: @ZdenekBarta - you can use various string class functions to perform the operations I mentioned.  You can search for specific substrings or characters in a string by using the string's `IndexOf()` method.  You can split a string on a character by using the string's `Split()` method.

Comment: i have this regex what return me float numbers [-]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+ but now i have just a little problem with read file. i get half numbers and after i get error

Comment: @ZdenekBarta - using the above answer, there is no need for you to use a regex statement to get the text you're trying to load into the float.  The float.TryParse() method will notify you by setting a flag whether or not it was successful in converting the value to a float.

Comment: so this way is faster?

Comment: I wouldn't say that it's faster or slower way, but it is a correct way to do what you need to do.  Furthermore, the time it requires to execute will be relatively small.

Comment: @ZdenekBarta - I've added some of the code to which I alluded earlier.  Hope this helps you.